# Is it possible to add done button inside the keyboard in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Currently i am working in phone 8 application, Using textbox with digit inputscope to enter phone number, user enter the phone number, then how to hide the keyboard? because no return button here, Is it possible to add done button inside the keyboard, please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One solution is to put a button in the application bar. It remains visible even when the keyboard is open.

Comment: thanks. I also thought that but I need a solution for phones keyboard

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly - you can't change the phone's keyboard buttons (except by changing inputscope)

Just follow the direction of what the People hub does when you edit the phone number - they add the save/cancel/delete button in the application bar.